# How to unpack Android Lollipop system.img.ext4 and add new language?

Tags: android, system

How can I unpack Android Lollipop rom .tar.md5
and unpaking system,img - system.img.ext4
in Windows and add new language to system file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unpack system.img.ext4:

1. Download Android Kitchen
2. Call find . -name simg2img
3. Copy whole folder in project directory
4. Build program simg2img
5. Copy the taken program to the folder contained system.img.ext4
6. Call ./simg2img system.img.ext4 system.img.raw
7. Call mount -o loop -t ext4 system.img.raw ./mnt
8. Enjoy